# Solve non-linear system of 16 equations

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I need a solution to a non-linear system of 16 equations, I am trying the following command and nothing is happening:

```
Solve[{1 + 2 a^2 + b^2 + 2 c^2 + 2 d^2 == 8 && 
1 + 2 a + b + 2 c + 2 d == 0 && 1 + 2 ae + bf + 2 g + 2 dh == 0 && 
1 + 2 ai + bj + 2 ck + 2 dl == 0 && 
2 + 2 am + bn + 2 co + 2 dp == 0 && 1 + 2 e + f + 2 g + 2 h == 0 &&
1 + 2 e^2 + f^2 + 2 g^2 + 2 h^2 == 8 && 
1 + 2 ei + fj + 2 gk + 2 hl == 0 && 
2 + 2 em + fn + 2 go + 2 hp == 0 && 1 + 2 i + j + 2 k + 2 l == 0 &&
1 + 2 i^2 + j^2 + 2 k^2 + 2 l^2 == 8 && 
2 + 2 im + jn + 2 ko + 2 lp == 0 && 
4 + 2 m^2 + n^2 + 2 o^2 + 2 p^2 == 8 && 
2 + 2 m + n + 2 o + 2 p == 0 && 1 + a + e + i + 2 m == 0 && 
1 + b + f + j + 2 n == 0}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, 
n, o, p}]
```

Is it the right way to get the answer?

Thanks

Comment: You need a space between variables to represent the multiplication e.g. `k o` rather than `ko`.

Comment: Some of your equations are linear. You can try to solve these and plug back the results in the remaining equations.

Answer (score 1):

FindInstance gives me (rather quickly) the following solution. Is this good enough for you ? Or are you looking for a specific set of solution ?

```
{{a -> -1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> -1, e -> 1, f -> 1, g -> -1, h -> -1, 
  i -> -1, j -> 1, k -> -1, l -> 1, m -> 0, n -> -2, o -> 0, p -> 0}}
```